# The definition of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Definition: A vector space consists of a set V (elements of V are called vectors), a field F (elements of F are called scalars), and two operations
• An operation called vector addition that takes two vectors v, w ∈ V ,
and produces a third vector, written $v + w ∈ V $.
• An operation called scalar multiplication that takes a scalar $c ∈ F$ and
a vector $v ∈ V $, and produces a new vector, written $cv ∈ V $.
which satisfy the following conditions (called axioms).

1. Associativity of vector addition: $(u + v) + w = u + (v + w)$ for all $u, v, w ∈ V $.
2. Existence of a zero vector: There is a vector in $V $, written $0$ and called the zero vector, which has the property that $u + 0 = u$ for all $u ∈ V$
3. Existence of negatives: For every $u ∈ V $, there is a vector in $V $, written $−u$ and called the negative of $u$, which has the property that $u + (−u) = 0$.
4. Associativity of multiplication: $(ab)u = a(bu)$ for any $a, b ∈ F$ and $u ∈ V$.
5. Distributivity: $(a + b)u = au + bu$ and $a(u + v) = au + av$ for all $a, b ∈ F$ and $u, v ∈ V $.
6. Unitarity: $1u = u$ for all $u ∈ V$.

I copied it from http://www.math.toronto.edu/gscott/WhatVS.pdf

And here comes my problem.

If  $V  $: Vector space ($\dim V=n$)

$W $: Subspace of $V$ ($\dim W=2<n$)

I call $W$ is a vector space, since I think $W$ meets the definition above. Is my idea right?

Comment: By vecter you mean vector, of course. - You are right, a subspace of a vector space is itself a vector space.

Comment: Indeed, if $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, then a subset $W$ of $V$ is, by _definition_, a subspace of $V$ iff it is a vector space over $F$. This is the reason that we only show closure under addition and scalar multiplication to show that a subset is a subspace since the other properties are automatically inherited since elements of $W$ are elements of $V$ as well.